# Sync value from textarea in EpicEditor after page loaded

Tags: javascript, real-time, synchronization, epiceditor

I am using **[EpicEditor](http://epiceditor.com/)** in one my project. So as per the [doc](http://epiceditor.com/), I have added `textarea` property to my textarea id, so when page load first time all content from textarea is showing in the EpicEditor. Works great!!!

**PROBLEM:**

---

I am getting real-time updates from server for that particular record and then I am updating the form fields value accordingly. So I am not able to set the new value in the EpicEditor. I have updated the reference textarea value but it will not sync to EpicEditor.

**SOLUTION**

---

I want to set the new value in the EpicEditor whenever some updates occurred on the reference textarea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

after you create an instance of epic editor with your options (`opt`) and load it. Put the text that you want to place in the epic editor as textarea value like this - `$("#myTextArea").val('your value'))` and call `me.editor._setupTextareaSync();`

```
var me = this;
var opts = {
    container: 'epiceditor',
    textarea: 'myTextArea',
    basePath: 'epiceditor',
    -------
    -------
}
var editor = new EpicEditor(opts);
me.editor.load();
$("#myTextArea").val('This is to be displayed in the epic editor');
me.editor._setupTextareaSync();
```

Cheers!

Comment: You should `importFile('filename', 'text in to go in editor')`. The textarea should update automatically when you do that. (If it does not, thats a bug and send us a bug report) Do _not_ use `_setupTextareaSync()`. As indicated with the underscore, this is a private, undocumented, unsupported and ephemeral method.

Answer (score 4):

```
var self = this;
var opts = {
    container: 'epiceditor',
    textarea: 'myTextArea',
    basePath: 'epiceditor',
...
}
var editor = new EpicEditor(opts);
self.editor.load();
// Now, import some content into the editor
// Since I don't know the filename I'm using `null` which will default to the current filename 
editor.importFile(null, 'This is to be displayed in the epic editor');
```

This *should* automatically update the textarea. If it does *not* update the textarea that's a bug and please send a ticket with your code and a reproducible case:https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor/issues/new

Comment: I have done it `$("#myTextArea").val('This is to be displayed in the epic editor');me.editor._setupTextareaSync();`. Is that correct? It's working perfectly.

Comment: See my comment above in your selected answer.

Comment: Yes, it's working but after calling `importFile` method I have to trigger preview or edit call to reflect the value in textarea. Is there a way to show latest content on textarea after calling `importFile`.

Comment: Just for anyone else reading this, @deepakb 's issue seems to have been fixed since then. Calling `importFile` as shown above updates the editor.